# How to clear task cache?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, .net-core

I've migrated my project from .NET Core 3.0 to .NET Core 3.1, and all my tests explode because they are conflicting with my previous ones in Task Explorer. How can I clear the task cache? They are not even valid/grayed out, but just throw exceptions forcing me to revert back to .NET Core 3.0...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The following TestContainer was not found 'D:\project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Project.Tests.dll'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<GetTestContainerAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQueryByTestsBase.<QueryTestContainerConfigurationsAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQueryByTestsBase.<GetContainersToUpdateInternalAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerConfigurationQuery.<GetContainersToUpdateAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<UpdateVsHierarchyContainers>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<UpdateContainersInternalAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Client.TestContainer.TestContainerProvider.<UpdateContainersAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<DetectChangedContainers>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.DiscoveryOperation.<StartDiscoverTestsAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.RunOperation.<RunTestsAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.Operation.<<Execute>b__37_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

As you can see above it's still looking for netcoreapp3.0 when in reality everything is 3.1. This is so stupid, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this after literally trying everything else by simply deleting my "vs" hidden folder located in the root folder of the visual studio solution.

Comment: Rebuild solution or even Rebuild Project. It fixes a lot of things.

Comment: @Christopher That didn't fix a dime. I've been tackling this problem for 4 HOURS! This was the only thing that worked.

Comment: I recently heard that Rebuild Solution does not nessesarily properly rebuild all Projects under the solution.